# Custom comparison operator for custom struct in multiset C++

Tags: c++, c++11, set, comparison-operators, multiset

I have the following structure

```
 struct Node                                                         
{
    int x0,y0,g,h,f;
    int *Grid[N][N];
    Node* parent=NULL;
    Node(int x=0,int y=0,int G=0,Node* node=NULL)
    {
        x0=x;
        y0=y;
        g=G;
        parent=node;
    }
}
```

and the `multiset` definition as follows

```
multiset<Node*,GridLess>open_list;
```

`Gridless` is the initial structure for comparison operator.

```
struct GridLess                                                                     
{
    bool operator()(const Node *a,const Node *b) const
    {
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
           for(j=0;j<N;j++)
           {
               if(*a->Grid[i][j]!=*b->Grid[i][j])
               {
                   return *a->Grid[i][j]<*b->Grid[i][j];
               }
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

My basic need was to find the `Node` in the `open_list` which has the same elements at same positions in grid using `multiset::count` or `multiset::find` which is completed by the above comparison operator.

Now I want to the `Node` in the `open_list` which has the same elements at same positions in grid as well as the same `Node::g` and `Node::f`

This is what I tried to use and failed

```
struct GridLess                                                                    
{
    bool operator()(const Node *a,const Node *b) const
    {
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
           for(j=0;j<N;j++)
           {
               if(*a->Grid[i][j]!=*b->Grid[i][j])
               {
                   return *a->Grid[i][j]<*b->Grid[i][j]||(*a->Grid[i][j]==*b->Grid[i][j]&&a->g<b->g)||((*a->Grid[i][j] == *b->Grid[i][j])&&(a->g==b->g)&&a->f<b->f);
               }
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Introducing two `Nodes` in the `open_list` with same grid but different g or f still results in `count=2`.

I tried checking for just the `Grid` and `Node::g` with the following

```
return *a->Grid[i][j]<*b->Grid[i][j]||(*a->Grid[i][j]==*b->Grid[i][j]&&a->g<b->g);
```

Even that doesn't work.

I need a comparison operator for this problem and explanation of how it works.

**EDIT**

I figured I am not clear with the `bool operator()` function as in when we write `return a<b` I understand it will return `true` if `a<b` but what will it return if `a==b` or `a>b` if this could be explained together with the question it would be really helpful.

Comment: This cannot be your real code. There is at least one missing semicolon, and the loop variables in `Gridless` are not declared anywhere. Please post **real code**.

Comment: @StoryTeller Each node contains NxN int pointers to an integer Grid

Comment: @ChristianHackl This is the code , I might have skipped the semicolon somwhere but `GridLess` is declared. Note: If you are copying and running on your machine put the `GridLess` struct above the `multiset` declaration.

Comment: Apologies, the syntax highlighting threw me off (although your naming convention isn't consistent, so you may want to think about that).

Comment: I'll definitely look into it, Thank you

Comment: @PhoenixDD: I really wanted to help you, but it sucks when you have to manually copy and paste bits and pieces of the posted code and fix one typo after the other until you finally think you've arrived at the real problem of the person who asks the question. You should instead post *one* complete yet short enough piece of code which requires only **one** copy & paste step and **no** typo fixes for the person who writes an answer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I am sorry, I'll keep that in mind next time I post a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You comparison of the `g` and `f` members has to be outside of the loop. As long as it is inside the loop, you do not compare the `g` and `f` members in case the `Grid` members are equal.

```
struct GridLess                                                                     
{
    bool operator()(const Node *a,const Node *b) const
    {
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
           for(j=0;j<N;j++)
           {
               if(*a->Grid[i][j]!=*b->Grid[i][j])
               {
                   return *a->Grid[i][j]<*b->Grid[i][j];
               }
           }
        }
        return std::tie(a->g, a->f) < std::tie(b->g, b->f);
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay, how do I do that? I tried putting it outside with the same results :/

Comment: Added code sample. Of course, all will break, if you have a nullptr `a`/`b` or `Grid`

Comment: Thanks a lot!, also I made an edit to my question as an extension , could you be kind enough to explain that as well? .

Comment: As to your follow-up question: a less operator should return `true`, if `a<b` and `false` in all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You comparison operator is not well behaved.  Compare just the grid points first in a loop, returning pointA pointB.  If they match, then compare the rest of the stuff.

Dunno why my answer got cut off, but it is the same as the complete one above. I think less than started a tag...

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I don't know how to make the comparison , I tried many things, it would be helpful if you could elaborate with an example on how to make is behave correctly .